# bash: whitespaces removed from string

Tags: string, bash, newline

I've written a small library function to help me exit when the script owner isn't root:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash   

# Exit for non-root user

exit_if_not_root() {
        if [ "$(id -u)" == "0" ]; then return; fi
        if [ -n "$1" ];
        then
                printf "%s" "$1"
        else
                printf "Only root should execute This script. Exiting now.\n"
        fi
        exit 1
}
```

Here I call it from another file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

source ../bashgimp.sh

exit_if_not_root "I strike quickly, being moved. But thou art not quickly moved to strike.\n You're not root, exiting with custom message."
```

And the output is:

```
I strike quickly, being moved. But thou art not quickly moved to strike.\n You're not root, exiting with custom message.
```

How can I get the newline to appear correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe do away with the `"%s"` and just

```
printf "$1"
```

would be simplest in this case.

ANSI-C escape sequences are not treated as such by default in strings - they are the same as other literals.  The form

```
$'ANSI text here'
```

will undergo backslash-escape replacement though.  ([*Ref.*](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html))

In your case though, as you're just `print`ing the formatted string provided, you may as well treat it as the format string rather than an argument.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But why didn't it work in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `echo -e` instead of `printf`

Answer (score 1):

Or quote the string correctly. You can have literal newlines in a quoted string, or use e.g. the `$'string'` quoting syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In the function, change the line to

```
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

And call the function like this

```
exit_if_not_root "text for line 1" "text for line2" "text for line 3"
```

`printf` will re-use the format string for as many value strings as you supply.